# Timers (Control.Concurrent.Timer) in Haskell: repeated execution

Tags: haskell, timer

Trying to figure out best practices to handle repeated actions in Haskell using `Control.Concurrent.Timer`. Can't find good examples.

Suppose I have repeated action that must be done in application. Say it's fetching data from some webpage.

```
import Control.Concurrent.Suspend.Lifted 
import Control.Concurrent.Timer

main :: IO ()
main = do
  url <- fetchUrl :: IO Url
  doSomethingWithUrl url
```

and I would like url to be fetched repeatly inside main so the data is always fresh. How could it be done?

Comment: How are you going to consume the "fresh" data?  Immediately after fetch? If so you can just `forever $ threadDelay time >> forkIO (fetchUrl >>= doSomethingWithUrl)`.  On the other hand, if doSomething is async then you'll want some mutable memory that fetch updates and doSomething reads.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks for your interest. In my case doSomething is Scotty web server loop (`scotty $ do ...`) so i guess it's async. The data consumed after fetch. `fetchUrl` which is API call of some service in my case has restriction on calls per IP per time.

Answer (score 1):

Your needs sound like they fit with an IORef or MVar.  Typed and not tested code is:

```
import Data.IORef (readIORef, writeIORef, newIORef)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay,forkIO)
import Control.Monad (void)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ref <- newIORef mempty {- or default value -}
  _ <- forkIO (updatePeriodically fetchUrl ref)
  scotty $ do
        liftIO (readIORef ref) >>= etcEtc

updatePeriodically :: (IO SomeType) -> IORef SomeType -> IO ()
updatePeriodically op ref =
    let update = op >>= writeIORef ref
    forever $ threadDelay periodInMicroSeconds >> void (forkIO update)
```

This isn't perfect, if one of the `fetchUrl` calls is badly delayed then its write could clobber a newer call that returned quickly.  That's probably a minor concern but you could handle it with a counter and compare and swap operation.

Comment: Thanks for your help again but I'd appreciate if I could see example with given (`Control.Concurrent.Timer`) lib. The part I can't figure out in it is the `IO TimerIO` in `repeatedTimer :: IO () -> Delay -> IO TimerIO`. In your example `updatePeriodically` has `IO ()` in the end and it's wrapped in `forever` loop. I don't understand much of more-or-less «low-level» stuff: IORed, forkIO etc.

Comment: Ok. I figured out that code to print "Hello" periodically might look like this using this libriary: 
``` 
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent.Suspend.Lifted
import Control.Concurrent.Timer

printHelloPeriodically :: IO ()
printHelloPeriodically = do
  void $ repeatedTimer (putStrLn "Hello") (sDelay 5)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  printHelloPeriodically
 ```

But how to deal with, say `getLine` (`fetchUrl`) and then print it periodically I can't understand